# how filter array of objects with same name and status in JS

Tags: javascript

Hi all I have following [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-davinci-qx85x5)

```
    [
      {service: { name: "Home" },status: "Generated", feeCharged:{id:1,fee:2},
      {service: { name: " Photography" },status: "requested",feeCharged:{id:2,fee:24}},
      {service: { name: "Electrical" },status: "requested",feeCharged:{id:6,fee:42}},
      {service: { name: "Electrical" },status: "Completed",feeCharged:{id:66,fee:23} },
      {service: { name: " Photography" },status: "Completed",feeCharged:{id:78,fee:11}},
      {service: { name: "Home" },status: "Generated",feeCharged:{id:45,fee:234}},
      {service: { name: "Electrical" }, status: "requested",feeCharged:{id:77,fee:3} },
      {service: { name: "Electrical" }, status: "requested",feeCharged:{id:4,fee:33} }
    ]
```

Now I am trying to filter them in new array by `service.name` and by `status` and add `count`.

The final result should be:

```
    [
      { name: "Home", status: "Generated", count: 2 },
      { name: "Photography", status: "requested", count: 1 },
      { name: "Photography", status: "Completed", count: 1 },
      { name: "Electrical", status: "requested", count: 3 },
      { name: "Electrical", status: "Completed", count: 1 }
    ]
```

So as you see in my final result if there are same `service.name` and `status` I am merging them into one object and setting count.

For filtering I try this, but it not working as I expected:

```
   let answer = [];

    data.forEach((x) => {
    if (!answer.some((y) => y.name === x.service.name)) {
      let newAnswer = {};
      newAnswer.name = x.service.name;
      newAnswer.value = 1;
      answer.push(newAnswer);
    } else {
      let existAnswer = answer.find((y) => y.name === x.service.name);
      existAnswer.value++;
    }
    });
```

Please help me to achieve that result, thanks.

Comment: How does a question that shows not even any _attempt_, get three upvotes in as many minutes? If anything, these should be close votes.

Comment: @CBroe I smell alt accounts

Comment: There are some questions, what language do you want the problem solved in? - Do you have any code examples of your current attempts?

Comment: Why is `name` in its own object?

Comment: I updated my question please look and help me if you can

Comment: Please vote for reopen, maybe other user can see and help me, thanks.

Comment: @someone, I fixed your code, please look `https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-sutherland-gowfmr`

Comment: Your code appears to work for `name`, but you've made no attempt to check for `status`.

Comment: @CBroe Please vote for reopening my question, thanks

Comment: @evolutionxbox Please vote for reopening my question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will be helpful for you?

```js
const data = [{ service: { name: "Home" }, status: "Generated", feeCharged: { id: 1, fee: 2 }},{ service: { name: " Photography" }, status: "requested", feeCharged: { id: 2, fee: 24 } }, { service: { name: "Electrical" }, status: "requested", feeCharged: { id: 6, fee: 42 } }, { service: { name: "Electrical" }, status: "Completed", feeCharged: { id: 66, fee: 23 } }, { service: { name: " Photography" }, status: "Completed", feeCharged: { id: 78, fee: 11 } }, { service: { name: "Home" }, status: "Generated", feeCharged: { id: 45, fee: 234 } }, { service: { name: "Electrical" }, status: "requested", feeCharged: { id: 77, fee: 3 } }, { service: { name: "Electrical" }, status: "requested", feeCharged: { id: 4, fee: 33 } }];


const res = Object.entries(data.reduce((a, e, nam) => { // get counts of name/status combinations
  nam = e.service.name + "|" + e.status;
  a[nam] = (a[nam] ?? 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {})).map(([k, n], t) =>{  // separate name/status key values again ... 
  t = k.split("|");
  return {name: t[0],status: t[1],count: n};
})

console.log(res)
```

(The current implementation uses `|` as a delimiter between the name and status value. Therefore it will fail if a name or status value contains this character.)